# How can you call a function when a page renders and when the browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function whenever a page's window is resized and when the page is first rendered. To do this, I am currently using the code below:

```html
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // Here will be my function
});
```

This calls the function every time the window is resized, but will the function be called when the page first renders? If no, how can this be done?

EDIT:.

I've updated my code so that it looks like this snippet:

```html
window.onload = (event) => {
    callName()
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    callName()
  });
};

function callName(){
    console.log('Hi Neo!')
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: you can call your function once the page loads using `onload` [load_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event#examples)

Comment: i updated question, can u look?

Comment: seems to work fine here as well : https://jsfiddle.net/f82cmnej/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function callName(){
  // Your functionality here...
    console.log('Hi Neo!')
} 

window.onload = () => { 
  callName()
  window.addEventListener('resize', callName);
}
```

Pen here: https://codepen.io/freedruk/pen/MWobaao

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JavaScript Window Resize Event</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>        
// Defining event listener function
function displayWindowSize(){
    // Get width and height of the window excluding scrollbars
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    
    // Display result inside a div element
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Width: " + w + ", " + "Height: " + h;
}
    
// Attaching the event listener function to window's resize event
window.addEventListener("resize", displayWindowSize);

// Calling the function for the first time
displayWindowSize();
</script>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Please resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use this as a example to get your desired result.